# Updating data of a nested list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a user object that contains a nested list and i need to change the value of a element in the 3rd list and return the user object.

I want to do this with linq, below is the nested loop.

```
foreach (User itm in user)
{
    if (itm.destinations!=null)
    {
        foreach (Models.Api.destinations.Destination dm in itm.destinations)
        {
            if (dm.destinationData != null)
            {
                foreach (Models.Api.destinations.DestinationData destData in dm.destinationData)
                {
                    if (destData.type == "phone" & destData.data!="")
                    { 
                          //i want to update the destData.data here .. something like
                         destData.data ='updated data';
                    }
                }
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

I want the updated data to be available in the user object

can someone help me achieve this with the LINQ

Thanks in advance
Tarak

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var x in
    (from itm in user
    where itm.destinations!=null
    from dm in itm.destinations
    where dm.destinationData != null
    from destData in dm.destinationData
    where destData.type == "phone" & destData.data != ""
    select new { itm, dm, destData }))
{
    /* put your update code here. */
}
```

You didn't give us what the update code should look like or even the object models for us to work from.